# How can I reliably observe which paths an executable is accessing?

Tags: sandbox, antivirus, strace, seccomp

In Linux or macOS, is there a way to observe which paths an x86-64 executable is trying to access, so that:

1. I can see the path of every file access, and the executable can't read content of any file, directly or indirectly, without me knowing about it.
2. The executable can't detect that it's being observed, OR I can detect that the executable is trying to detect whether it's being observed.

There are two mechanisms that I know of: seccomp and strace. Seccomp/BPF fails on point 1, because it sees pointer arguments, but it can't reliably dereference them. Strace fails on point 2, because there are trivial checks for it that aren't themselves traceable.

The executables will be running in a container or VM, but I still want to know how much they snoop around their sandbox.

---

Background: what I'm writing is basically a heuristics-based antivirus. I want to check whether 3rd party programs are "well-behaved" according to my spec. I am fully aware that this is fools' errand, false sense of security, and there are countless ways to evade such checks. My goal is to catch obvious attempts, and raise the bar for exploitation and evasion at least a notch above "totally trivial for any kid". I know the right approach would be to not use arbitrary executable code in the first place, but that part is outside of my control, and I'm just trying to make a bad situation less bad.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux you can use fanotify to monitor all the file open/closes from all processes, then in user-space you can filter it to just the processes you want to monitor.

It might require some special work to make sure the monitor process is in the right mount namespace as the container though.